# Undefined offset: 7 in /home/test/index.php

Tags: php, notice

I am struggling with the undefined notice comes and sometimes not. I am not sure why I am having this error.

```
foreach($_POST['toplevel_menus'] as $toplevel_menu){
    $toplevel_extracted = explode("|", $toplevel_menu);
    $submenu_id = $toplevel_extracted[5];
    if(isset($_POST[$submenu_id]) && !empty($_POST[$submenu_id])){
        foreach($_POST[$submenu_id] as $submenu){ 
            $extracted = explode("|" $submenu); 
            $submenu_name = (isset($_POST[$subname][$extracted[1]])) 
                               ? trim($_POST[$subname][$extracted[1]])
                               : "";                                                                       
         }
     }
}
```

The line number 7 is

```
$submenu_name = (isset($_POST[$subname][$extracted[1]])) ? trim($_POST[$subname][$extracted[1]]) : "";
```

Comment: It is not line 7, it is index 7. You are trying to access the index 7 of something that isn't really an array or that doens't have this index.

Comment: I dont think thats a line number. I think it is saying you have an index called `7` or rather you are trying to address one but it does not exist

Comment: for testing, use `echo count($extracted);` inside your `foreach`

Comment: @Sablefoste I dont think he is trying to address `$extracted` with any index above 1

Comment: @RiggsFolly, sorry, right!  He should `var_dump($subname);` after the explode, to see how many elements there are.

Comment: @Sablefoste thats more like it

Comment: Yes, as RiggsFolly said, some top level menus do not have sub menu array in it. That's why I used `if(isset($_POST[$submenu_id]) && !empty($_POST[$submenu_id])){` That's not enough?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to always access arrays via index is to check them with isset first. This way you can make sure to avoid such errors.

Comment: This is a comment _at best_ Please dont write answers that are not answers as you will just get downvoted and take even longer to get enough points to be allowed to comment